# Why doesn't my scrollTop work?

Tags: jquery, scroll, overflow, scrolltop

I have problem with the behavior of the scrollTop(). I'll show a small example:

```js
/*----Code JQuery-----*/
$(".box").scroll(function() {
     var $this = $(this);
        var oldTop = $this.scrollTop();
        var newTop = (Math.round(oldTop / 200) ) * 200; 
        $this.scrollTop(newTop);
  });
```

```css
/*----Code CSS-----*/
div.box{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
div.small{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
       <div class="small" style="background-color: brown">All your text content...<br></div>
       <div class="small" style="background-color: pink">All your text content...<br></div>
       <div class="small" style="background-color: blue">All your text content...<br></div>
       <div class="small" style="background-color: purple">All your text content...<br></div>
       <div class="small" style="background-color: yellow">All your text content...<br></div>
       <div class="small" style="background-color:green">All your text content...<br></div>     
       <div class="small" style="background-color:orange">All your text content...<br></div> 
       <div class="small" style="background-color:red">All your text content...<br></div>
</div>
```

The scroll of mouse don't work very well, and the buttons of the scroll bar too. Thanks you very much, for you help. (I'm sorry for my english...)

Comment: Well, if the rounding of `scroll / 200` is below `0.5`, the mutiplication will be `0 * 200`...

Comment: It's true, if I click on the right area in scroll bar, it's moved successfully (`scroll / 200 > 0.5` and return `1 * 200`). If I move the scroll of mouse (should do the same) it doesn't work very well, and the button of _top_ and _bottom_ don't work nothing and it should be `scroll / 200 > 0.5` to return `1 * 200`. I think that the oldTop is captured incorrectly. I debugged of code and this value is wrong when I use scroll of mouse and the buttons of the scroll bar. Thanks for you help